# From Server; SQL, arrayList | To Client; TableView

Tags: sql, arraylist, javafx, tableview, fxml

I'm trying to view SQL database table using JavaFX tableView.

I have a DBHandler class on the Server with a method to "select" all items from the table, then I store the values in resultSet. I then add the contents of the resultSet to an arrayList of object class Room using the while loop. The arrayList is then sent to the client over socket.

The client reads the object as an instance of the Room class, the object is added to another arrayList, which is added to an observableList, which is used to add the data to the Table view.

However, the code/logic does not work. On the client side I get a 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Room' error.

Client: FXMLController::

```
public class FXMLControl implements Initializable {
    @FXML private TableView tblRooms;
    @FXML private TableColumn roomNo;
    @FXML private TableColumn capacity;
    @FXML private TableColumn type;

    @FXML private void onViewRooms(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        MainApp main = new MainApp();
        main.viewRooms();
        tblRooms.setEditable(true);
        ObservableList<Room> listo = FXCollections.observableArrayList(main.rooms);
        tblRooms.setItems(listo);
}}
```

Client: MainApp::

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
   ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

   public void viewRooms() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
      String sendServer = "viewRooms");
      oos.writeObject(sendServer);
      oos.flush();

      Room roomer = (Room) ois.readObject();
      rooms.add(roomer);
}}
```

Server:

```
public class server {

   public static void clientSession() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
      String userInput = ois.readObject();

      switch(userInput){
         case "viewRooms":
         DBHandler dbhandler = new DBHandler(username,password,url);
         dbhandler.viewRooms();

         oos.writeObject(databaseManager.rooms);
         oos.flush();}
}}
```

Server: DBHandler::

```
public class DBHandler {
   ArrayList<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

   void viewRooms() throws SQLException {
   //db connection setup
      String query = "SELECT * FROM ROOM";
      PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()){
         rooms.add(new Room(rec.getInt("ROOMNO"),rec.getInt("CAPACITY"),rec.getString("TYPE")));
         }
      }}
```

Room class:

```
public class Room implements Serializanle {
   private int roomNo;
   private int capacity;
   private String type;
// contructors ...
// getter and setter methods
}
```

The user should be able to press the button(onViewRooms), and the server will be 'alerted' to send back contents in the db. 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: As you describe, you are sending an `ArrayList` over the stream. So you cannot cast it to a `Room` when you receive it.

Comment: @James_D But then how would I send multiple objects of Room class?

Comment: You're already sending multiple objects aren't you? You're sending a single list, which contains multiple rooms, no?

Comment: @James_D Without knowing how many I'm receiving/sending

Comment: Surely you're only sending one list.

Comment: @James_D I'm sending a single arraylist, are you suggesting I should send object of the Room class or should I cast the arraylist to observablelist on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server sends a single list to the stream:

```
oos.writeObject(databaseManager.rooms);
```

but when you receive the list you try to cast it to a `Room`:

```
Room roomer = (Room) ois.readObject();
```

Since an `ArrayList` is not a `Room`, this obviously fails with a class cast exception.

Just cast directly to a list:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
   List<Room> rooms ;

   public void viewRooms() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
      String sendServer = "viewRooms");
      oos.writeObject(sendServer);
      oos.flush();

      rooms = (List<Room>) ois.readObject();
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however after implementing the above ^, it seems to only have to address not the values. i.e. Room@61951e4a, Room@1b8db140, Room@384f3d21

Comment: @ZhemeArts That is a completely different issue. Just do some basic research on this site to find solutions to it.